# Extract opcodes from the entry point of an executable

Tags: artificial-intelligence, executable, virus, objdump, opcodes

I am working with the objdump command to decompile an executable and extract the opcodes, I need to know if I can extract the opcodes from the entry point of the file, because now I do it from the sections.

Comment: yes you can, read the file.

Comment: what file format are you using?

Comment: I'm working with executable files

Comment: @old_timer can you help me?

Comment: there are many operating systems in the world and many executable file formats and operating systems are generally limited to one or a few...